# pyqtgraph: Multiple y-axis on left side?

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have found the MultiplePlotAxes-example in pyqtgraph 
and extended it with one more y-axis (see code below).
So there are 3 y-axis on the right side now.

Is there a way to get all 3 y-axis from the right side to the left side so that there are in total 4 y-axis on the left side?:

Because for example 
`ax3 = pg.AxisItem('left')`only changes the orientation of the label and ticks of an axis but not the position of the axis relative to the origin of co-ordinates.

## modifed MultiplePlotAxes-example

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

pg.mkQApp()

pw = pg.PlotWidget()
pw.show()
pw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: MultiplePlotAxes')
p1 = pw.plotItem
p1.setLabels(left='axis 1')


p2 = pg.ViewBox()
p1.showAxis('right')
p1.scene().addItem(p2)
p1.getAxis('right').linkToView(p2)
p2.setXLink(p1)
p1.getAxis('right').setLabel('axis2', color='#0000ff')


p3 = pg.ViewBox()
ax3 = pg.AxisItem('right')

p1.layout.addItem(ax3, 2, 3)
p1.scene().addItem(p3)

p4 = pg.ViewBox()
ax4 = pg.AxisItem('right')

p1.layout.addItem(ax4, 2, 4)
p1.scene().addItem(p4)

ax3.linkToView(p3)
p3.setXLink(p1)
ax3.setZValue(-10000)
ax3.setLabel('axis 3', color='#ff0000')

ax4.linkToView(p4)
p4.setXLink(p1)
ax4.setZValue(-10000)
ax4.setLabel('axis 4', color='#ff5555')


def updateViews():
    global p1, p2, p3, p4
    p2.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
    p3.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
    p4.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())

    p2.linkedViewChanged(p1.vb, p2.XAxis)
    p3.linkedViewChanged(p1.vb, p3.XAxis)
    p4.linkedViewChanged(p1.vb, p4.XAxis)

updateViews()
p1.vb.sigResized.connect(updateViews)


p1.plot([1,2,4,8,16,32])
p2.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem([10,20,40,80,40,20], pen='b'))
p3.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem([3200,1600,800,400,200,100], pen='r'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 22):

A while ago since I have posted the original question which from my findings wasn't answered appropriate elsewhere and not in three weeks so I pull this one up by myself...

It seriously took me a while until I had figured it out, but yeah, right now there is a good solution and just in case someone ever picks this thread up, here is how it should look like, which is by the way a common representation of data at my institution.
The pyqtgraph plot with multiple y-axis: https://i.stack.imgur.com/joP5l.png

@Luke: Why not use this one as example for multiple left y-axis?

Here is its code:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui,  QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

pg.mkQApp()

# Axis
a2 = pg.AxisItem("left")
a3 = pg.AxisItem("left")
a4 = pg.AxisItem("left")
a5 = pg.AxisItem("left")
a6 = pg.AxisItem("left")

# ViewBoxes
v2 = pg.ViewBox()
v3 = pg.ViewBox()
v4 = pg.ViewBox()
v5 = pg.ViewBox()
v6 = pg.ViewBox()

# main view
pw = pg.GraphicsView()
pw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: multiple y-axis')
pw.show()

# layout
l = pg.GraphicsLayout()
pw.setCentralWidget(l)

# add axis to layout
## watch the col parameter here for the position
l.addItem(a2, row = 2, col = 5,  rowspan=1, colspan=1)
l.addItem(a3, row = 2, col = 4,  rowspan=1, colspan=1)
l.addItem(a4, row = 2, col = 3,  rowspan=1, colspan=1)
l.addItem(a5, row = 2, col = 2,  rowspan=1, colspan=1)
l.addItem(a6, row = 2, col = 1,  rowspan=1, colspan=1)

# plotitem and viewbox
## at least one plotitem is used whioch holds its own viewbox and left axis
pI = pg.PlotItem()
v1 = pI.vb # reference to viewbox of the plotitem
l.addItem(pI, row = 2, col = 6,  rowspan=1, colspan=1) # add plotitem to layout

# add viewboxes to layout 
l.scene().addItem(v2)
l.scene().addItem(v3)
l.scene().addItem(v4)
l.scene().addItem(v5)
l.scene().addItem(v6)

# link axis with viewboxes
a2.linkToView(v2)
a3.linkToView(v3)
a4.linkToView(v4)
a5.linkToView(v5)
a6.linkToView(v6)

# link viewboxes
v2.setXLink(v1)
v3.setXLink(v2)
v4.setXLink(v3)
v5.setXLink(v4)
v6.setXLink(v5)

# axes labels
pI.getAxis("left").setLabel('axis 1 in ViewBox of PlotItem', color='#FFFFFF')
a2.setLabel('axis 2 in Viewbox 2', color='#2E2EFE')
a3.setLabel('axis 3 in Viewbox 3', color='#2EFEF7')
a4.setLabel('axis 4 in Viewbox 4', color='#2EFE2E')
a5.setLabel('axis 5 in Viewbox 5', color='#FFFF00')
a6.setLabel('axis 6 in Viewbox 6', color='#FE2E64')

# slot: update view when resized
def updateViews():

    v2.setGeometry(v1.sceneBoundingRect())
    v3.setGeometry(v1.sceneBoundingRect())
    v4.setGeometry(v1.sceneBoundingRect())
    v5.setGeometry(v1.sceneBoundingRect())
    v6.setGeometry(v1.sceneBoundingRect())

# data
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y1 = [0,4,6,8,10,4]
y2 = [0,5,7,9,11,3]
y3 = [0,1,2,3,4,12]
y4 = [0,8,0.3,0.4,2,5]
y5 = [0,1,6,4,2,1]
y6 = [0,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6]

# plot
v1.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y1, pen='#FFFFFF'))
v2.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y2, pen='#2E2EFE'))
v3.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y3, pen='#2EFEF7'))
v4.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y4, pen='#2EFE2E'))
v5.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y5, pen='#FFFF00'))
v6.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y6, pen='#FE2E64'))

# updates when resized
v1.sigResized.connect(updateViews)

# autorange once to fit views at start
v2.enableAutoRange(axis= pg.ViewBox.XYAxes, enable=True)
v3.enableAutoRange(axis= pg.ViewBox.XYAxes, enable=True)
v4.enableAutoRange(axis= pg.ViewBox.XYAxes, enable=True)
v5.enableAutoRange(axis= pg.ViewBox.XYAxes, enable=True)
v6.enableAutoRange(axis= pg.ViewBox.XYAxes, enable=True)

updateViews()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: FWI, a pull request for this functionnality is in currently in  progress (https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/1359).

Comment: Looks interesting, but the zero (y) points don't align (match up)

Comment: For the aligned y axis see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931474/how-can-i-have-multiple-left-axisitems-with-the-same-alignment-position-using-py