# How can I have multiple left axisItems with the same alignment/position using pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, plot, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I wonder if someone can help me out. I am trying to convert the MultiplePlotAxes.py example in pyqtgraph so that the all the axes are on the right side and aligned. Here is my code which I have added an extra plot:

```
"""
Demonstrates a way to put multiple axes around a single plot.
(This will eventually become a built-in feature of PlotItem)
"""
#import initExample  ## Add path to library (just for examples; you do not need this)

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

pg.mkQApp()

pw = pg.PlotWidget()
pw.show()
pw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: MultiplePlotAxes')
p1 = pw.plotItem
p1.setLabels(left='axis 1')

## create a new ViewBox, link the right axis to its coordinate system
p2 = pg.ViewBox()
p1.showAxis('right')
p1.scene().addItem(p2)
p1.getAxis('right').linkToView(p2)
p2.setXLink(p1)
p1.getAxis('right').setLabel('axis2', color='#0000ff')

## create third ViewBox.
## this time we need to create a new axis as well.
p3 = pg.ViewBox()
ax3 = pg.AxisItem('right')
p1.layout.addItem(ax3, 2, 3)
p1.scene().addItem(p3)
ax3.linkToView(p3)
p3.setXLink(p1)
ax3.setZValue(-10000)
ax3.setLabel('axis 3', color='#ff0000')

## create forth ViewBox.
## this time we need to create a new axis as well.
p4 = pg.ViewBox()
ax4 = pg.AxisItem('right')
p1.layout.addItem(ax4, 2, 4)
p1.scene().addItem(p4)
ax4.linkToView(p4)
p4.setXLink(p1)
ax4.setZValue(-10000)
ax4.setLabel('axis 4', color='#2EFEF7')

## Handle view resizing
def updateViews():
    ## view has resized; update auxiliary views to match
    global p1, p2, p3, p4
    p2.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
    p3.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
    p4.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())

    ## need to re-update linked axes since this was called
    ## incorrectly while views had different shapes.
    ## (probably this should be handled in ViewBox.resizeEvent)
    p2.linkedViewChanged(p1.vb, p2.XAxis)
    p3.linkedViewChanged(p1.vb, p3.XAxis)
    p4.linkedViewChanged(p1.vb, p4.XAxis)

updateViews()
p1.vb.sigResized.connect(updateViews)

p1.plot([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32])
p2.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem([1, 2, 4, 9, 16, 32], pen='b'))
p3.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem([1, 2, 4, 7, 16, 32], pen='r'))
p4.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem([1, 3, 5, 7, 17, 32], pen='c'))

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

This produces the following picture which I have added a red arrow showing what I want to do. 
[image]

Based on what I have been able to figure out I can do this using pg.GraphicsLayout(). However, the axisItem directly associated with plotItem and the created axisItems don't match because the one attached to the plotitem is smaller.

Here is a picture of what I believe is happening:

[image]

This is my problem as I want them to all align. In the attached code you can addItem(axes,2,1) to the right but it doesn't work on the left. Anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue, saw this post, was disappointed with the lack of an answer, but I finally did manage a fix so figured I would post here.

If you could post the code you have for the axis on the right, I could patch that up, but basically what I did was attach the bottom axis to a a row of its own.

```
self.main_pI = pg.PlotItem()
self.axis_bottom = self.main_pI.getAxis('bottom')
self.axis_bottom.setLabel('Time (seconds)', color='#ffffff')
self.layout.addItem(self.main_pI, row=1, col=2, rowspan=2)
self.layout.addItem(self.axis_bottom, row=3, col=2, rowspan=2)
```

I'm a noob at pyqtgraph so I'm sure I'm going to butcher this terminology, but I detach the 'bottom' axis, and reattach it to the layout, where it's on a row of its own.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What you suggests works and this makes them all the same size. However I was hoping to make them all the same size as the one attached to the original plot and not the other way around. The reason for this is when you look at a point and want to read it off the axis, it will be wrong. I tried to paste my extended example here but there is not enough room for it.

Comment: In my implementation, all the subsequent axes are the size of the gray one (meaning they line up with the plot).  Mr RC which posted another solution shows a similar thing, where they put the bottom axes into a a row that is 1 higher than that of the plot area, and the y-axes.

Comment: Its fine. When you have a plot item and add an extra axis to the bottom or to the right it will line up correctly. However, it is not possible to say have 5 right axis inside a plot item. Instead you have to use a grid layout and in this situation the method I mention below works ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured something out that is not perfect but is pretty close. Using the suggestion above and adding an extra axis item to the bottom in the appropriate space and blanking it out I have come up with this. All lines  line up but not perfectly with the y-axis but close enough to get away with it. Heres the difference

Original
[image]
New 
[image]
Heres the code:

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

pg.mkQApp()

# Axis
a2 = pg.AxisItem("left")
a3 = pg.AxisItem("left")
a4 = pg.AxisItem("left")  
a5 = pg.AxisItem("left")
a6 = pg.AxisItem("left")

# ViewBoxes
v2 = pg.ViewBox()
v3 = pg.ViewBox()
v4 = pg.ViewBox()
v5 = pg.ViewBox()
v6 = pg.ViewBox()

# main view
pw = pg.GraphicsView()
pw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: multiple y-axis')
pw.show()

# layout
l = pg.GraphicsLayout()
pw.setCentralWidget(l)

# add axis to layout
## watch the col parameter here for the position
l.addItem(a2, row=1, col=5, rowspan=1, colspan=1)
l.addItem(a3, row=1, col=4, rowspan=1, colspan=1)
l.addItem(a4, row=1, col=3, rowspan=1, colspan=1)
l.addItem(a5, row=1, col=2, rowspan=1, colspan=1)
l.addItem(a6, row=1, col=1, rowspan=1, colspan=1)

# Blank axis used for aligning things
ax = pg.AxisItem(orientation='bottom')
ax.setPen('#000000')
pos = (2,2)
l.addItem(ax, *pos)

# plotitem and viewbox
## at least one plotitem is used whioch holds its own viewbox and left axis
pI = pg.PlotItem()
v1 = pI.vb  # reference to viewbox of the plotitem
l.addItem(pI, row=1, col=8, rowspan=2, colspan=1)  # add plotitem to layout

# split off 1st axis and put to side
pI.axis_left = pI.getAxis('left')
pos = (1,7)
l.addItem(pI.axis_left, *pos)

# add viewboxes to layout
l.scene().addItem(v2)
l.scene().addItem(v3)
l.scene().addItem(v4)
l.scene().addItem(v5)
l.scene().addItem(v6)

# link axis with viewboxes
a2.linkToView(v2)
a3.linkToView(v3)
a4.linkToView(v4)
a5.linkToView(v5)
a6.linkToView(v6)

# link viewboxes
v2.setXLink(v1)
v3.setXLink(v2)
v4.setXLink(v3)
v5.setXLink(v4)
v6.setXLink(v5)

# axes labels
pI.getAxis("left").setLabel('axis 1 in ViewBox of PlotItem', color='#FFFFFF')
a2.setLabel('axis 2 in Viewbox 2', color='#2E2EFE')
a3.setLabel('axis 3 in Viewbox 3', color='#2EFEF7')
a4.setLabel('axis 4 in Viewbox 4', color='#2EFE2E')
a5.setLabel('axis 5 in Viewbox 5', color='#FFFF00')
a6.setLabel('axis 6 in Viewbox 6', color='#FE2E64')


# slot: update view when resized
def updateViews():
    v2.setGeometry(v1.sceneBoundingRect())
    v3.setGeometry(v1.sceneBoundingRect())
    v4.setGeometry(v1.sceneBoundingRect())
    v5.setGeometry(v1.sceneBoundingRect())
    v6.setGeometry(v1.sceneBoundingRect())

# data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y1 = [0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 4]
y2 = [0, 5, 7, 9, 11, 3]
y3 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12]
y4 = [0, 8, 0.3, 0.4, 2, 5]
y5 = [0, 1, 6, 4, 2, 1]
y6 = [0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]

# plot
v1.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y1, pen='#FFFFFF'))
v2.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y2, pen='#2E2EFE'))
v3.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y3, pen='#2EFEF7'))
v4.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y4, pen='#2EFE2E'))
v5.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y5, pen='#FFFF00'))
v6.addItem(pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y6, pen='#FE2E64'))

# updates when resized
v1.sigResized.connect(updateViews)

# autorange once to fit views at start
v2.enableAutoRange(axis=pg.ViewBox.XYAxes, enable=True)
v3.enableAutoRange(axis=pg.ViewBox.XYAxes, enable=True)
v4.enableAutoRange(axis=pg.ViewBox.XYAxes, enable=True)
v5.enableAutoRange(axis=pg.ViewBox.XYAxes, enable=True)
v6.enableAutoRange(axis=pg.ViewBox.XYAxes, enable=True)

updateViews()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Hope it helps anyone who has the same problem in the future